# How do i generate link in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuejs3

I am using a button in a template that will link to whatever the id of the link is.

```
<router-link to="/{{$.route.params.id}}/detail" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Add</router-link>
```

where $route.params.id is id of the current link.

I want to is that when I click the Add button say in Books page where $route.params.id = Books with link = localhost:8080/Books, it will link to localhost:8080/Books/detail.
However, if I do that and clik the Add button, it will redirect to localhost:8080/{{$route.params.id}}/detail.
What should I do to fix it?

I am quite begineer in Vue.js. I tried looking at the documentation but couldn't quite understand as it said about using arrays and creating it in  script...../script  and stuff. Can someone explain the process to me and also if i can generate the link without involving script?

Comment: Pass an object to the `to` prop instead of creating link yourself. `<router-link :to="{name:'your-route-name',params:{id:$route.params.id}'}">Add</router-link>`. It will generate link for you.

Comment: Could you explain what 'your-route-name' mean? 
I tried using various route combinations but didn't work out.

Comment: 'your-route-name' is the name of the route, on **router.js** (the router file in your project) you can add a property named **name** to your routes. You can see more details here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html